# Dont submit the form after jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form which have the jquery validation. My problem is, I just want to validate the form and I dont want to submit. How to do that?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind "valid()" function to an event wich does't send the form.

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function(){
  $("#yourform").valid();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to happen in the submit button, do:

```
$("#your_form").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

But if you want to validate by scripting anytime, do:

```
  //Validates but doesn't submit. Validates and returns true or false indicating if it was valid.
  $("#form").data('validator').form();
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

    $('#submit').submit(function(e){

       //validate form 

       e.preventDefault(); // or return false ;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), pass `onsubmit: false` to the validate method:

```
$('#someForm').validate({
    onsubmit: false
});
```